# Summing up fields with field calculator in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator

I am trying to sum up the content of the fields of my attribute table that have the string `_Wert` in their name. I tried to do it as shown in the following algorithm. But something is wrong with my formula because it won't get a result. Do you have any idea how to sum up fields like that?

> Test = 'C:\Users\User\Vereinigungen_Test.shp'

```py
def sumfields():

    #Geometrien reparieren 
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': Test,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    tmp_repair = processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params)

    #add field sum
    layer = tmp_repair ['OUTPUT']
    allfields = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()] # iterate over the layer's fields and store the fieldnames in a list
    fields_wertung = [s for s in allfields if '_Wert' in s]
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'Sum_Wertung',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 1,
        'FORMULA': sum(fields_wertung),
        'INPUT': layer,
        'NEW_FIELD': True,
        'OUTPUT': 'C:\\Users\\User\\Summe_Wertung_Test.shp'
    }
    processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params)
```

Comment: Have you checked that `fields_wertung` is what you expect it to be before it is then used? Does it work if you replace `sum(fields_wertung)` with `sum(["f1_Wert","f2_Wert"])` (where those are a couple of fields you know exist). Are you getting an error message? Or an output of all zeroes?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the sum of each "_Wert" value in a feature as a new column? Because I don't think the `sum` function works like that. It sums the whole column of a single field, with optional grouping. If you want something like `f1_Wert + f2_Wert + f3_Wert` you may need to construct that as a python string and pass that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('wert')[0]
new_field = 'wertsum'
wertfields = [f.name() for f in layer.fields() if 'Wert' in f.name()] #List the fields
formula = ' + '.join([f' "{wertfield}"' for wertfield in wertfields]) #Create the formula string, it should look like: ' "_Wert1" +  "_Wert2" +  "_Wert3"' with my data

calculated = processing.run("native:fieldcalculator", {'INPUT':layer,'FIELD_NAME':new_field,
    'FIELD_TYPE':0,'FIELD_LENGTH':0,'FIELD_PRECISION':0,'FORMULA':formula,
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(calculated)
```

[image]